# Отображение полей в связе многие ко многим в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

У меня есть сущности "событие" и "участник". Связь многие-ко-многим. У каждого участника должен быть билет на событие.

***Выглядит это вот так:***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Эти сущности в `Hibernate`:***

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "action")
public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Organization organization;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "action_member", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "action_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "member_id")})
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Member> members;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Moscow")
    private Date createdAt;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String email;
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "action_member", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "action_id")})
    private List<Action> actions;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", timezone = "Europe/Moscow")
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

***Проблема в том***, что я не понимаю как правильно отобразить в этой схеме билет. Могу я как-то всем участникам добавить поле `ticket`, которое будет зависеть от конкретного события ? Как это будет выглядеть ?

Comment: Видимо, потребуется сущность для `action_member`. Посмотрите примеры на  [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns) или на [mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В данном примере нет отношения `many to many`. Такое отношение показывает только связь между разными строками таблиц и не может содержать какие то еще данные.*

---

Вру, всетаки и такое соотношение является `many to many`, но не совсем каноничное. В любом случае, в разрезе ORM это ничего не меняет.

Тут только одно решение: вам нужно реализовать саму таблицу `action_member` как сущность и уже к ней пролинковать Action  и Member.

Comment: Почему это не `many to many` ? У нас есть множество пользователей у каждого из которых может быть множество `action`. Справедливо и обратное. Почему тогда это не `many to many` ? Таблица отношений может содержать дополнительные поля, но ведь это же не отменяет семантику сущностей.

Comment: Ну ок, с учетом того что в большинстве баз такое отношение все равно реализуют с помощью 3ей таблицы и не редко такие поля добавляют(сейчас погуглил и не 1 раз такое встретил). Но даже если отбросить палемику о том что канонично (ну уж так меня учили), а что нет, со стороны ORM это всеравно будут 3 таблицы, а не 2. И хочешь, не хочешь, но чтобы получить значение "из серединки", эту "серединку" тоже надо определить.

Comment: Вот именно. С точки зрения теории баз данных в этом нет ничего криминального. Хотел вот узнать про возможные решения со стороны `ORM`. Спасибо за ответ!